# My external drive appears in "disks" but doesn't appear in left column

Tags: drive

I have an external drive (1tb) the is formatted and passworded within Ubuntu. It used to work fine, I plug it in and get prompted for the password. Now when I plug it in, nothing happens, but I can see it is there in Disks. Under assessment it says "disk is ok". The partition type is "Linux (bootable)". this is what I see under Disks.

I mean it doesn't appear in the left column of my desktop where external drives usually appear for me to click on. I guess that means it's not mounted.

[image]

Comment: What is "left column" in your title? Explain in your question. Use "edit".

Comment: I can't see that the disk is mounted... please [edit] your question to indicate how it is mounted and which os you are using.

Comment: Ok edited now. I guess it's not mounted then? Can I just mount in on command line?

Comment: Yes you can. If that fails, error messages may point to the issue, so post command and output here.